# How to get bracket style border for QWidget using stylesheets?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I want to use a style sheet to make `QWidget` border look like brackets.

[image: Screenshot]

My reference is the [Qt style sheet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html), but how can I customize it to look like the one in the screenshot?

This is as far as I can get, showing only the left and right borders.

```css
QWidget{
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-width: 0px 1px;
}
```

Can it be done with a pure style sheet?

Answer (score 3):

The example in the screenshot in the question can only be achieved with an image AFAIK, even in a Web browser with full CSS support. With Qt you actually have three options of using a custom image behind/around your widget.

To whit: `background-image`, `border-image`, and `image`:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html

There's an example for using `border-image` already here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images

I like SVG images personally, so here's an example with a quick one I whipped up. This is using the `image` property to overlay a transparent, scalable SVG of the brackets. (Note that for the CSS to even apply to a button, the native border may need to be overridden like I have in the example.)

[image]

```cpp
// Requires Qt svg module, as in `QT += svg`.
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDialog d;
    d.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    QToolBar* tb = new QToolBar(&d);
    tb->setIconSize(QSize(48, 48));
    d.layout()->addWidget(tb);

    QIcon icon("./so-icon.svg");
    for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i)
        tb->addAction(icon, QStringLiteral("Action %1").arg(i));

    QToolButton *btn = qobject_cast<QToolButton*>(tb->widgetForAction(tb->actions().at(1)));
    btn->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral(
        "QToolButton {"
            "border: none;"  // To override some styles like WindowsVista and Macintosh
            "image: url(./brackets.svg);"
        "}"
    ));

    return d.exec();
}
```

https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.svg

File *brackets.svg*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="48px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 48 48" enable-background="new 0 0 48 48" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#047F18" d="M12,44H4V4h8V0H0v48h12V44z"/>
<path fill="#047F18" d="M36,4h8v40h-8v4h12V0H36V4z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use the [CSS border-image Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

The other possibility is to override the `paintEvent` method on your parent widget, calling the baseline class `paintEvent` get everything painted, and then paint the appropriate borders on top wherever you like.

Comment: Qt Style Sheet only supports css 2.1 so many of the css 3 features are not available in Qt.

Comment: There's an example of using `border-image` right in the [CSS reference docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images), and has been there as long as I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

One could use `QLinearGradient` to segment the top and bottom borders to 3 parts. Left and right get the color of the border, and the middle part gets the color of the widget background.

In this example stylesheet, green is the outer color, white is the inner.

```css
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 5px solid qlineargradient(spread: pad,x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:0, 
                                  stop: 0 green,
                                  stop: 0.2 green,
                                  stop: 0.21 white,
                                  stop: 0.8 white,
                                  stop: 0.81 green
                                  stop: 1 green);
border-left:  5px solid green;
border-right: 5px solid green;
```

There needs to be a small fraction separating them to achieve a solid color.

Here's how it looks:

[image: Bracket background]

The downside of this method, is that diagonal gap in each corner, which is caused by the borders not painted on top of each other, which makes it look segmented.